# Disabling page items does not work after refreshing them

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have several radio group on my page. There is a dynamic action that needs to reset all the radio groups to default values and then disable.

I used apex `Disable` action and set the affected items to all my radio groups. That worked fine, but once I added `Refresh` action for all those radio groups BEFORE Disable, the Disable stopped working - The DA resets the radio groups to default but does not disable them. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Can you say on what events the refresh/Disable is triggered?

Comment: selecting a value in another radio group

Comment: In 19.2 I don't see an option value for `Select [Radiogroup]`

Comment: there is a Change event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing an item fires off an Ajax request to the server. The response from the request can take some time. The disable action is firing before the response arrives and then the item is refreshed with the new values (not disabled).

To get around this, break your Dynamic Action into two:

1. On change of the other radio group, refresh the target radio group. This is just like the one you have now, but without the disable action.
2. After refresh of the target radio group, disable the target radio group.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it

Comment: Sorry for the delayed follow up, but if you need to differentiate between when the user is changing the value of the radio group and when the Refresh action does it, you can use the following as a JavaScript Expression condition in the Dynamic Action: `!this.browserEvent.originalEvent` Learn more about that here: https://www.talkapex.com/2019/03/how-to-refresh-a-report-only-once-with-multiple-dependant-cascading-lovs/ (same concept)